# Select colour addition/subtraction when drawing a path in Android

Tags: android, graphics

I need to select how the paths are drawn on the target canvas (using [Canvas.drawPath()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#drawPath(android.graphics.Path,%20android.graphics.Paint))): e.g. using CMYK (subtractive) or RGB (additive) mode. (In [Cairo](http://cairographics.org/manual/), there is a function [cairo_set_operator()](http://cairographics.org/manual/cairo-cairo-t.html#cairo-set-operator) which does this: i need similar functionality in Android.)

I found the [ColorFilter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/ColorFilter.html) class, but it seems to have different purpose.

Thanx in advance

György Kövesdi

---

I have no reply for a long time, but found the answer:

```
Xfermode filter = new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.ADD);
paint.setXfermode(filter);
```

The class PorterDuffXfermode has similar possibilities to Cairo.

Comment: Please include some screenshot of what you need.